# What is the estimated number of variant surface glycoproteins that trypansomes can express?

Tags: proteins, parasitology

In "Vaccination against trypanosomiasis" by Greca and Magez they assert that there are "innumerable" variant surface glycoproteins that the parasite can express. What does innumerable mean here? These proteins presumably have to conform to some sort of structural conditions, so I don't believe it is truly infinite. Is there an estimate of the order of magnitude of the number of these proteins?